# Придаточное определительное после сказуемого

Tags: синтаксис, придаточное-предложение

> Рекомендованная доза препарата составляет 150 мг, **которую** вводят подкожно один раз в неделю.

Придаточное определительное относится к подлежащему, но отделено от него сказуемым. Корректна ли такая структура предложения?

Comment: Звучит кривовато, хотя на 10-ый раз привыкаешь. Да и не придаточное это будет, а два независимых предложения. Рекомендованная доза препарата составляет 150 мг. Которую вводят подкожно один раз в неделю. Лучше переработать предложения

Comment: @user190920: у вас в наращении правильно оставить только Й (неправильно начинать с гласной).

Comment: Спасибо. Почему-то думал что Ы как и Й согласная

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я сомневаюсь в правильности этого предложения: *Рекомендованная **доза** препарата составляет 150 мг, **которую вводят** подкожно один раз в неделю.*

Более корректно выглядят такие записи:

*Рекомендованную дозу препарата **в количестве 150 мг** вводят подкожно один раз в неделю.*
Или: *Рекомендованная доза препарата **составляет 150 мг и вводится** подкожно один раз в неделю.*

**Пояснение**

1. Придаточные с союзным словом "которые" бывают двух видов: определительные (можно вставить указательное слово ТАКОЙ) и распространительные (нельзя вставить указательное слово).

Придаточные второго вида фактически соответствуют такому варианту: *Рекомендованная доза препарата составляет 150 мг. **Она вводится** подкожно один раз в неделю.*

2. **О правильности построения определительных предложений** можно почитать у Розенталя: §211. Причастные обороты (пункт 3 и 4) http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm

Пункт 4. В зависимости от значения возможно различное согласование причастий. Ср.: **Часть** книг, **предназначенная** для выставки, уже получена (получены все книги, предназначенные для выставки) – Часть **книг, предназначенных** для выставки, уже получена (получены не все книги, предназначенные для выставки).

Ср. также: **количество** электроэнергии, **потребляемое**... (подчеркивается количественная сторона) – количество **электроэнергии**, **потребляемой**... (характеризуется объект, о части которого идет речь); две тысячи рублей, взятых взаймы – десять тысяч рублей, взятые у сестры (Л. Толстой).

Такие варианты согласования встречаются в тех случаях, когда **причастный оборот определяет не отдельное слово, а словосочетание.**

Но в приведенном предложении не та структура, о которой здесь говорится. То есть там **нет словосочетания из двух существительных,** с которыми согласуется союзное слово, так что и выбирать нечего.

Comment: Не очень интересно это.

Comment: Да, Артем? Ваш  вариант вам больше нравится, он интереснее?  Кажется, Розенталь его не запрещает, но стиль здесь  нечто среднее между разговорным и просторечным.  А вот мое  предложение хоть в учебник записывай, ага? Что скажете по поводу стиля?

Comment: Нет, ваш ответ было интересно почитать, я просто хотел, чтобы вы сказали своё мнение и по поводу моего варианта. :))

Comment: Интересный у вас психологический прием :))  Ну если у Толстого оборот согласуется количественным сочетанием, то ваш вариант тоже не хуже. Пожалуй, надо это отметить.

Comment: Да какие там приёмы?..)) Спасибо, я тоже отметил. =)

Comment: Как по мне, наиболее лаконичный и без ошибок вариант таков: **Рекомендованная доза препарата составляет 150 мг, её вводят один раз в неделю, подкожно.** Поясню, почему не *"её вводят подкожно один раз в неделю"*: в таком виде инструкция говорит, что подкожно доза вводится один раз в неделю, а внутримышечно или внутривенно — неопределённое количество раз.

Comment: @Nektoid
Возможно, в этой теме есть какая-то особая специфика, но мне сложно определить иерархию двух обстоятельств (количество и вид процедур).  Нормальным, с моей точки зрения, выглядит любое оформление: неоднородные или уточняющие отношения, а также свободный порядок их следования.

Comment: @Sharon с точки зрения грамматики оба оформления верны, да. Указанный мною нюанс относится к сфере (уже, наверное, надоевшего Вам) писательского мастерства :)

Comment: Может быть, может быть... А я-то думала, к сфере медицины :)

Answer (score 2):

Правильнее, на мой взгляд, так (не к подлежащему, а к количеству):

*Рекомендованная доза препарата составляет 150 мг, *котор**ые*** вводят подкожно один раз в неделю.*

150 мг = они (вне падежей фразы)